# Operational monad with interpreter in arbitrary monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm using the [operational monad](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/articles/operational-monad.html) by Heinrich Apfelmus.
I'd like to parameterize the interpreter with the monad for the result type.
The following version of my code compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Control.Monad.Operational

data EloI a where
    Display :: Int -> EloI ()

type Elo a = Program EloI a

interpret :: Monad m => (Int -> m ())
                     -> Elo a
                     -> Int
                     -> m a
interpret display = interp
  where
    interp :: Monad m => Elo a -> Int -> m a
    interp = eval . view
    eval :: Monad m => ProgramView EloI a -> Int -> m a
    eval (Display i :>>= is) s = interp (is ()) s
```

Now I change the last line to

```
eval (Display i :>>= is) s = display i >> interp (is ()) s
```

and type inference doesn't succeed anymore, I get the output

*Could not deduce (m ~ m1) from the context (Monad m)

bound by the type signature for interpret :: Monad m => (Int -> m ()) -> Elo a -> Int -> m a
(...)*

When I remove the type signature for interp, I get an additional error (could not deduce (a1 ~ a)).
When I change all m to IO (like in the tic tac toe example for the operational monad), then it compiles again.
Am I trying something that does not make sense or can I provide some hint to GHC? I have to admit I'm not sure that I need this flexibility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because the `m` in the local type signatures are fresh type variables, so they promise to work with *any* Monad. If you use `display`, `eval` can only work for the specific monad `display` uses. It should work if you a) remove the local type signatures, or b) bring the type variable `m` into scope

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
...
interpret :: forall m. (Int -> m ()) -> Elo a -> Int -> m a
```

Comment: I didn't even try a) (althaugh I usually don't use local type signatures) because of the following statement in the example code "Note that since ProgramView is a GADT, the type annotation for eval is mandatory."